# Facebook Connect showFeedDialog

Tags: facebook

I would like to use FB.Connect.showFeedDialog(...), but without it being a popup, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately it is not currently possible to use Feed Forms directly within an iFrame or Facebook Connect application. The only option is to use FBJS built-in wrappers FB.Connect.showFeedDialog() and FB.Connect.showAddSectionButton().

You might also want to take a look at the following (if you haven't already, which you probably have):

[Creating a Popup Dialog in an IFrame](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Creating_a_Popup_Dialog_in_an_IFrame)
[Publishing Feed Stories to Facebook](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Publishing_Feed_Stories_to_Facebook)

Comment: Thanks, I found out how to put it in an iframe, but is there a way to position it, so it is not centered?

Comment: I would try using FBJS to change the style. First you'll need to get the element (var elem = document.getElementById('something').getFirstChild() or something similar). Then you can use the FBJS setStyle() function, i.e. elem.setStyle('position','absolute'); elem.setStyle('top','100px'); etc.